# Text not displaying when being mapped from Array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Used a mapping function to display information from an array into 3 tiers, from what I can see everything seems right but none of the information is being displayed, can someone look at the code and tell me if there is something that I am missing

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

function Plans() {

    const notePlans = [
    {
        name:"NoteZ Free",
        price:"$0",
        features: [
            "1 user per account",
            "Unlimited notes",
            "4 categories to choose from",
            "Help Support"
            ]
    },
    {
        name:"NoteZ +",
        price:"$5",
        features: [
            "2-4 users per account",
            "Unlimited notes",
            "Folder system for notes",
            "Custom categories",
            "Custom templates to choose from",
            "Help Support"
        ]
    },
    {
        name:"NoteZ Infinity",
        price:"$10",
        features: [
            "Unlimited users per account",
            "Unlimited notes",
            "Folder system for notes",
            "Custom categories",
            "Full integration with MealZ",
            "Full integration with WorkoutZ",
            "Custom templates to choose from",
            "Help Support"
        ]
    }
    ]

  return (
    <Main>
        <div className='pricing-container'>
            {notePlans.map((plan) => (
                <div className='pricing-card' key={plan.name}>
                    <h2>{plan.name}</h2>
                    <p>{plan.price}</p>
                    <ul>
                        {plan.features.map((feature,index) => (
                            <li key={index}>{feature}</li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                    <button>Buy Now</button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    </Main>
  )
}

const Main = styled.div`
    width:100%;

    .pricing-container{
        border:1px solid black;
        color black;
        
    }
`;



export default Plans
```

I tried adding the key when the console reported an error saying that a key was needed.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-carson-fed4z9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This seems to work. Can you explain again what error are you getting?

Comment: The text doesn't display. Im not getting any breaking errors as when I add another component the one added does show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const Main = styled.div`
    width:100%;

    .pricing-container{
        border:1px solid black;
        color: black;
        
    }
`;
```

There was a missing **":"**, after `color`.
Also it works here: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-jepsen-5zdl2y?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The code seems to work in both links provided in this answer and the one in the comment above but the text still doesn't display for some reason

Comment: @NS1 if this doesn't work even you should check your project configurations and dependencies installed. Since it can run in the sandbox, the error must be somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Try adding return statement in your map callback function like this :

```
<div className='pricing-container'>
        {notePlans.map((plan) => 
            return (
            <div className='pricing-card' key={plan.name}>
                <h2>{plan.name}</h2>
                <p>{plan.price}</p>
                <ul>
                    {plan.features.map((feature,index) => (
                        <li key={index}>{feature}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
```